# Nuxt + Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I'm writing my own nuxt plugin for firebase/firestore. I'm loading it in the config with:

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/firestore.js',
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist', ssr: false }
],
```

The file itself looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {
  ...
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

const settings = {
  timestampsInSnapshots: true
}
const store = firebase.firestore()
store.settings(settings)


class Firestore {
  ...
}
const firestore = new Firestore()

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('firestore', firestore)
}
```

When I'm running `npm run dev` it tries to create a firebase instance on each automatic reload. How can I have it only create this instance once?

`Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).`

Comment: You may config the firebase twice in your project. Try to find it and remove one.

Comment: You should call initializeApp() in your app setup (initialization/bootstrap code) so that it's only run once. Not sure why Vue, React, Next, et all invoke imported code more than once, but there's probably a better answer there as well. Note that creating a class named `Firestore` sounds fairly suspicious; probably reinventing wheels here and may run into conflicts.

Comment: I could rename Firestore, but the functions inside are just preset functions, like getAllUsers() etc.
The bootstrap is called each time on a hot reload for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `firebase.apps` to see if its loaded. If your only loading it once, then you can just check the length. If you have multiple then you could check each apps name. Once it helped for me

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({});
}
```